# kendo.saveAs "Download excel" is not working on server but working on local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have implemented the Kendo.saveAs fro download the template and it is working on local env but while uploading it on server it stop working and showing bellow error. **500 Internal server Error**

Code:

```
 kendo.saveAs({
        dataURI: "data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh",
        fileName: "Mytemplate.xlsx",
        proxyURL: TemplateUrl,
        forceProxy: true
    });
```

controller:

```
   public ActionResult Download(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
    {
        return File(
            System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(
                ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Areas\\MyApp\\UploadTemplates"), fileName)),
            System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the path with slashes and backslashes is correct?

Comment: i think Yes, because same path is working in local env

Comment: You could put a try/catch in your controller method, and log or return the exception message to get some clarity of what the issue is. If that path is working locally, then are the files with the filename present on the server path location?